# Is it okay to decorate a Service class?

Tags: design-patterns

I have an external system that I need to call from specific Service. 
For me that's an additional responsibility for that Service, and I planned to decorate it.

On the other hand, calling external system is quite important and treated as part of business, so I would also include it in the Service, so I follow the operation script approach suggested by [P of EAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)

Is it okay to decorate a Service class, as I couldn't find such approach in any reference projects?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess if you decorate service class, you are gonna be using only decorated version anyway, since it contains important business logic without which the operation would be incomplete. If that is the case, there is no need to decorate it, inherit from it, etc. Just add that additional behavior to the old class, or delegate it to someone else. It doesn't make sense to expose class without self-sufficient behavior (very similar to abstract class) if you don't plan to have multiple derivatives of it.

Comment: It might happen that different configuration uses Service that does not call external system. In that case I guess decorating Service will help